# How to map two objects using only their interfaces with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map two objects by using only their interfaces but the returned value is always an object with empty / null properties:

Domain interface:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    int Age { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

DAL interface:

```
public interface ICustomerEntity
{
    int Age { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

I'm trying to map them with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

        ICustomer customer1 = new Customer("John", 30);
        ICustomer customer2 = new Customer("Mary", 30);

        var customerEntity = Mapper.Map<ICustomer, ICustomerEntity>(customer1);
        var customerReturned = Mapper.Map<ICustomer>(customerEntity);
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile<DomainToEntitiesMappingProfile>();
            c.AddProfile<EntitiesToDomainMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

And these are my profiles:

```
class DomainToEntitiesMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ICustomer, ICustomerEntity>()
            .Include<Customer, CustomerEntity>();
    }
}

class EntitiesToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ICustomerEntity, ICustomer>()
            .Include<CustomerEntity, Customer>();
    }
}
```

When I try to map the concrete classes (removing the interfaces), it works just fine, but I don't want to couple my mappings to the concrete classes.

How to achieve that?

I've tried the same approach with AutoMapper 6 and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your interface lack any public setters:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    int Age { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

You need to add them:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    int Age { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```